# Symfony 5.1 php 7.3 In ArrayNode.php line 320: Unrecognized options

Tags: php, symfony, php7

в какой-то момент решила обновить композер и тут случилось случился провал

**composer update**

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!  In ArrayNode.php line 320:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Unrecognized options "migrations_paths, storage, doctrine_migrations_bundle  
!!    " under "doctrine_migrations". Available options are "all_or_nothing", "col  
!!    umn_length", "column_name", "custom_template", "dir_name", "executed_at_col  
!!    umn_name", "name", "namespace", "organize_migrations", "table_name".         
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

composer.json

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.5",
    "symfony/asset": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/intl": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/mime": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/notifier": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/process": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/string": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/translation": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "5.1.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.19",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": {
      "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
      "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
      "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "@auto-scripts"
    ]
  },
  "conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "symfony": {
      "allow-contrib": false,
      "require": "5.1.*"
    }
  }
}
```

doctine_migration.yaml

```
doctrine_migrations:
    migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations'
    storage:
        table_storage:
            table_name: 'migration_versions'
            version_column_name: 'version'
            version_column_length: 255
            executed_at_column_name: 'executed_at'
            execution_time_column_name: 'execution_time'
    doctrine-migrations-bundle:
        branches: ["1.3", "master"]
        maintained_branches: ["1.3", "master"]
        master_alias: "2.0"
```

я пыталась переустановить php version 7.2->7.3, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0". Давайте посмотрим что это такое. https://github.com/symfony/orm-pack/blob/v1.1.0/composer.json и тут можно видеть `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2"` в котором есть вот такая схема https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/v2.0.0/Resources/config/schema/doctrine_migrations-1.0.xsd. В схеме действительно не описаны migrations_paths, storage и doctrine_migrations_bundle. Эти опции (кроме doctrine_migrations_bundle) появляются в третьей версии бандла https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.0.x/Resources/config/schema/doctrine_migrations-3.0.xsd. Такое впечатление, что произошёл откат версии бандла с 3 на 2 версию.

Интересно что в orm-pack не было migration-bundle до 1.0.4 версии. В 1.0.8 Появилось такое `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "*"`. Кажется вы установили его в эту чудесную пору. Постарался некто [goetas](https://github.com/goetas). Это привело к проблемам, которые решили откатом ко второй версии бандла миграций. А уже это исправление привело к проблемам подобной вашей.

Вероятно вам следует переустановить бандл или исправить конфиг doctine_migration.yaml.

Comment: да, я просто переустановила бандл, и удалила почти все с  doctine_migration.yaml., это помогло

Comment: привет, у меня точно такая же проблема, но переустановка ничего не меняет. Не могли бы вы мне помочь?

Comment: @Claudeloicelanga а конфиг doctine_migration.yaml вы удаляете и ставите заново? Проблема точно такая же или сообщение об ошибке отличается?